# How to reinitialize NSMutableDictionary in an ARC project?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, nsmutabledictionary

I have a class level NSMutableDictionary object that I need to initialize, and reinitialize. Since my project is ARC, I am not sure if I can use release.

What is correct way to do it?

My current code results into a crash:

```
myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: value1,@"key1", 
value2,@"key2", nil];
```

Note that this crash is when I do this 2nd time after class is loaded, not the first time. So the problem is definitely that I am re-allocating it.

In any case (crash or not), I want a leak-free way to handle this in an ARC project.

Comment: What's the error? With ARC you can't call release. Simply assigning a new dictionary like you are is fine. The error will tell us more.

Comment: The correct way to handle this situation and all others is to read the documentation. This is very elementary question, telling us that you haven't read a bit from the docs.

Comment: Not sure why so many people simply don't understand my question. I anyway read up the docs and am clear now, in any case there are hundreds like these doing rounds of SOF, not just this one. Am voting to close this.

Comment: What should be re-assigned is variable, not the object. You can reinitialize the object, but what shown in the code is re-assigning a newly created object into existing variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do like that

```
 -(void)ViewDidLoad
 {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      myDict =  [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: value1,@"key1", value2,    @"key2", nil];
 }
```

when you re using it please do not alloc/init again instead you can do as following

```
if([[myDict allKeys]count])
{
     [myDict removeAllObjects];
}
```

**and set again value inside the dictionary**

```
 [myDict setValue:@"Abc" forKey:@"xyz"];
```

Comment: Yes I know this is possible, somehow I want that I could all my keys and values with one statement, like I did with initWithObjectsAndKeys. Any possibility?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "re-intialize", but you can always remove all the keys and values in the dictionary and put them in again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply alloc+init it again, all your previous values will be released and new object will be reassigned to the same object/Dictionary.

Comment: How can you add values to it if you set it to `nil`?

Comment: Sure but you said to set it to `nil`, not do another `alloc/init`. There is no need to set it to `nil` if you just reassign the variable to a new instance.

Comment: ok, As i said nil, then no need to remove all keys/values, as it will be released automatically.

Comment: What the OP is doing is already correct. No need to set it to `nil`. No need to remove existing values. Simply assign a new instance. That's it. As written, your answer states that the variable should be set to `nil` and nothing else. I think you actually know what to do but what you wrote in your answer is misleading at best.

Comment: I think that is what I am doing here, but it's failing. What I am wondering though is, is it right? I am not just concerned about crash here. Maybe I will try removeall, then add. But my concern is: how much can we take ARC for granted? Can we be assured initWithObjectsAndKeys will do the necessary cleanup if it's set to something?

Comment: My goodness, man, tell us the error :) please note: there is nothing wrong with your initial statement as you wrote it. And don't be concerned about memory leakage-it won't leak. But initWithObjectsAndKeys has nothing to do with cleanup, ARC has - read up on it.

Comment: @NiravBhatt: ARC does memory management for you. Do dont have to worry about it. even if your retain count reaches 1,2,3,4. ARC will keep track of all. And all weak references will be release.

Comment: I didn't care, just got rid of it using removeall+set. As the question title indicates, I need a surer way to do this, without messing up memory that's all. Many a times methods like inits does things internally, your line about ARC partially answers my question, thanks!